# "Go to page" buttons should have the ability to choose a specific number

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, user-experience

When you are on the Questions, Tags, Users, or Companies pages you can scroll to the bottom of the page and see buttons to move forward/backward between the pages and also skip to the beginning/end:

[image]

However, if for example you wanted to access page 1058 you would have no way to do this without continually advancing the page you are viewing through the entire list.

I think that these buttons could be improved by adding a way to manually enter a page number.

It might not seem like this would pose any benefit, but then again why should we only be able to easily view the beginning and end of pages in a list?

I think a possible way to add this functionality would be by adding a hover check for both of the ellipses which causes a dropdown text field to appear like so:

[image]

Comment: I can't, in honesty, see when you would want to navigate to a specific page number. If you really want to, however, you could just amend the URL appropriately.

Comment: @Larnu you and I know page 1337 has all the good stuff. How do we get there quickly?

Comment: [Page 1337](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*+or+ssms*+or+tsql+or+azure-sql-database+or+azure-data-studio?sort=Newest&uqlId=49232&page=1337&pagesize=30) @rene . :)

Comment: Is this standard behaviour somewhere? I have seen quite a few paginations use ellipses for large gaps between page numbers, I don't know that I've ever seen one which allows specific page number selection from inside that range.

Comment: I have seen it, @HenryEcker .

Comment: @Larnu One use case: trying to skip *n* pages to search for a certain date.  Of course, that might be better expressed with search operators...

Comment: Can you edit the URL directly as a workaround for the time being?

Comment: Another Usercase: How many Users have already filled in the 'SO Survey 2022'...? => Count the `Census` Badges: Tot_Nb (of Pages) - 3490 = [211](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644?page=211) Pages > x60 (Users/Badges per Page) => 12,660 Users for now... :cool:

Comment: Binary search would be better serviced by larger intervals between visible page numbers. Some sites have buttons for 5 pages back, 10 pages back, 100 pages back or forwards etc.

Comment: What about "*Roman Search*" then with [I,V,X,L,C,D,M] for +[1,5,10,50,100,500,1000]...!? That would be Fun...!! (Spoiler about April Fools MMXXIII...!)

Answer (score -19, accepted):

> I think that these buttons could be improved by adding a way to manually enter a page number.

I think there should be a surface that can be incremented/decremented with mouse scrolling.

Comment: What do you mean by "a surface"? Some non-desktop thing?

Comment: I think they're talking about how you can scroll to change the value of a `type="number"`

Comment: Tapping (or scrolling) up to page 1337 will still take an obnoxious amount of time.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas make speed proportional to page range and decrease increase with total scroll duration.

Comment: It sounds about as good of an experience as sites/apps that use a 'calendar selector' widget for date of birth but neglect a year/decade jump. Scrolling decades day by day, regardless of how "fast" you go, is a pain. Paging is similar if you're going more than, say, 10. Tolerance may vary. Also mouse scrolling isn't very accessible.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas still better than having to lean forward to type in a number when I'm sitting back away from the keyboard. I'm not saying the typing option shouldn't be available, but I also want the scroll option (if every mobile has it no reason SE shouldn't).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas *"more than, say, 10"* that's nonsense it can work for any range and if it's 100 or more still good.

Comment: As I said: "Tolerance may vary." I find most scroll-y widgets entirely unintuitive and obnoxious so my tolerance is low. And your irritation with leaning forward to find your keyboard is equal to my irritation to leaning forward and having to find my mouse. ;)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas no a fair argument because having the functionality doesn't force you to use it, but not having the functionality is impeditive for the other users.

Comment: @bad_coder I think this would be good solution if combined with my above idea. If you hover over the ellipse and then the text box appears, you would be able to see what page you have selected when scrolling. This would at least minimize the "effort" of clicking the box, typing a number, pressing enter etc. Depending upon the speed of the mouse wheel scroll, the page number could increment very fast or more slowly.

Comment: @MFerguson yes, the ideal solution would be having both functionalities...

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add this workaround (mentioned in the comments) as an answer.

---

> by adding a way to manually enter a page number.

Manually entering a page number in the proposed text field, IMO, is the same as manually entering a page number in the URL.

You can navigate to the second page, where the URL will automatically change to:

> [...]stackoverflow.com/questions?**tab=newest&page=2**

where you can enter any page number you want. For example, [page 1058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=1058):

> [...]stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=**1058**